# Centre ImageView horizontally inside a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, alignment, uitableview, accessoryview

I am having a bit of a problem putting my image view in the middle of the cell.

**I have a tableView cell with:**
a label which is left aligned
a UIImageView (which is to be in the middle of the screen but not overlap the AccessoryView or Accessory)
an optional AccessoryView or Accessory.

**I then have a header cell:** 
a label which is left aligned
a UIImageView (which is to be in the middle of the screen)

The problem is that i want all the images to be aligned Horizontally (including the header) but the AccessoryView/Accessory throws off my calculation.  The image view is a ScaleAspectFit.  Currently i have set the width to be the full width of the contentView.

Does anyone know roughly how I would accomplish this? I have read people say to put in an empty view into the cells that won't have an AccessoryView or Accessory but this doesnt help with the Header? others have hardcoded values?

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you please be a bit more clearer about what you are trying to do? If possible attach a screenshot.

Am i understanding right? That you want to align all imageViews including header and normal cells both but don't want the image to appear behind the accessory view?

Comment: Yeah, sorry basically i want to make all the images appear in a straight line including the header cell.  Without overlapping the AccessoryView or Accessory.

Comment: You could simply align all the imageView to its superView, add a leading to the label on the left that can be greater than equal to a value and set a width for the imageView. (Of course you will have to add vertical constraints as per your need too!)

Edit: You will also have to add a trailing that is greater than the place where the accessory view normally appears.

Answer (score 0):

Change imageView frame x origin after your cell layout subviews. Just add this to your cell definition.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let imageViewWidth = self.imageView?.frame.width
    let imageViewOriginX = (screenWidth - imageViewWidth!) / 2
    self.customImageView.frame.origin.x = imageViewOriginX 
}
```